# How to configure spring batch processing in web based application

Tags: spring-batch

can anyone tell me how to configure spring batch in web based java application.
I have read a lot on the internet but there isn't any example of web based spring batch processing.
can anybody share any web based example of spring batch processing?

Answer (score 0):

All invocations of spring batch could easily be done with JobOperator. Actually there is plenty of information available in [spring batch documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html).

```
private JobOperator jobOperator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public String launch() {
    List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances("myJob", 0, 10);

    List<String> all = jobInstances.stream()
            .map(jobExplorer::getJobExecutions)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(JobExecution::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return all;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public Long restartJob(@RequestParam("execId") Long executionId) {
    return jobOperator.restart(executionId);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public Long startJob() {
    return jobOperator.start("jobName", "parameters...");
}
```